# C++: Printing dynamically allocated array to console behaving weirdly

Tags: c++, xcode

I am having weird behavior with my print function but I am wondering if it is an IDE issue or an issue with the fact that my code and target/executable is stored on an external hard drive. OR if it is my code. it will randomly print things like '/323' '2u3m' that kind of stuff. Then I run it again and it prints totally fine.

```
int WordList::print() const {
    
    if (m_list != nullptr) {
        for(int i=0; i<(m_count-1); i++){
            cout << m_list[i] << " ";
        }
    cout << m_list[m_count-1] << endl;
    return m_count;
    }
    else
    
    return -1;
}
```

Also the computer I am using has 4gb of RAM and is often kinda slow... I am using Xcode

I realize you do not see the rest of my code and that their may be some kind of issue there.

I haven't been coding very long so this kind of behavior maybe a sign of something but I haven't had the experience to know what it is so I am hoping someone here can help me out!

Thanks!

Member variables:

```
class WordList {
.
.
.
private:

    unsigned int m_count;   // Number of words currently in list
    unsigned int m_max;     // The total size of the list.
    char**       m_list;    // The list storing the words

};
```

Adding where I think a problem would lie if there is one:

```
int WordList::add(const char word[]) {
    if (strlen(word)==0) {
          return -2;
        }
    if (m_list == nullptr ){
        m_list = new char*[1];
        m_list[m_count] = new char (strlen(word));
        strcpy (m_list[m_count], word);
        m_count++;
        m_max ++;
        return -2;
        }
    if (m_count == 0 && m_list != nullptr ) {
        m_list[m_count] = new char (strlen(word));
        strcpy (m_list[m_count], word);
        m_count++;
        return 0;
        }
    if (m_count < m_max) {
        m_list[m_count] = new char (strlen(word));
        strcpy (m_list[m_count], word);
        m_count++;
        return 0;
        }
    if (m_count == m_max) {
        m_list[m_count] = new char (strlen(word));
        strcpy (m_list[m_count], word);
        m_count++;
        m_max ++;
        return 1;
        }
else
    return -2;
}
```

So I am using this to store char arrays, I have to only use things in the cstring library hence the reason I am doing everything the hard way.

This is a project for school if it isn't obvious and I know there are details I may have left out as to the greater scope of the project but I think it should make sense with the information I have given.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: *Then I run it again and it prints totally fine* -- With the small code you posted, I can easily put together something that has all sorts of undefined behavior.  We have no idea where `m_list` comes from, whether it is valid, whether `m_count` is valid, whether `WordList` is a valid object, etc. That's why we need to see the rest of your program.

Comment: Okay thanks for the responses I will try to clear it up.

Comment: Okay I just posted my implementation of an add function that adds to class WordLists as well as the member variables details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line, and lines that are similar to this:

`m_list[m_count] = new char (strlen(word));`

are wrong for two reasons.

First, that line does not allocate `strlen(word)` chars dynamically.  What it does is it creates a *single* character dynamically, with the value of that character equal to `strlen(word)`.

Second, even if you allocated correctly, it does not allocate enough memory to hold the terminating `null` character when you call `strcpy` later on.

Thus your program had memory overwrites and undefined behavior.

The fix for this line (and other similar lines is):

`m_list[m_count] = new char [strlen(word) + 1];`

Note the `[ ]` and the addition of the `+1` to make room for the null terminator.

---

Other issues that are suspicious is your usage of `m_count` and `m_list[m_count]`.  Where do you actually *increase* the size of `m_list` to hold more items?

---

Having said all this, why are you not simply using `std::string`, so that these types of mistakes are not committed?  Also, why not simply `std::vector<std::string> m_list` instead of raw pointers?

Comment: Thank you for the help. It is an assignment designed to teach dynamic memory management and structuring that data correctly so only cstrings where allowed. So not ```std::string`` or anything else that makes it easier unfortunately

Comment: As for where I increase the size of m_list to hold more pointers I am frustrated to see that I don't think I am doing that correctly. I think I originally though that m_list[m_count] = new char [strlen(word) + 1]; would do that. I am trying to figure out how I would add another char pointer to the end of the m_list array?

Comment: I didn't have any undefined behavior using that technique so I never though twice about it

Comment: Undefined behavior means "anything can happen", including "work".  As to increasing the size of `m_list`, somewhere you have to reallocate to the new size, and then copy over the old contents to the new contents, delete the old contents.  It is much more involved than simply incrementing `m_count`.